# does a remote process continue if initiated from my local? What are the rules on this?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, crash

Scenario:

1. I `ssh` into remote server A from my terminal on my local computer
2. Now, logged into server A, I execute (for example):

   ```
   scp -rp root@serverB:/path/to/files .
   ```

and the process begins transferring files from A to B
3. I'm watching the progress and my computer dies.

Does the process continue on server A-B?  What is the justification for this if it's the case?  Are there processes that are dependent on the connection between my local and server A to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not continue. Once your connection to the serverA is closed, the system terminates your shell and all processes running under them including `scp`. The rationale behind this is hygiene. You don't want to have running processes on your server, which do not belong to any active user.

You can prevent this behavior using `screen`, `tmux` or simply `nohup`, as described in many other questions.